# Sequence Diagram Out Of Existing Java Code

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, architecture, eclipse-plugin, papyrus

I have Java code setup in eclipse Juno.

I would like to generate "Sequence Diagram" out of the existing class.

To do this, I tried to use "Papyrus" but no success.

Can we create "Sequence Diagrams" using Papyrus ?

If yes, could you please suggest any tutorial on that ?

If No, then which other plugin I could use to generate "Sequence Diagrams" out of "Java Code" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to automatically generate sequence diagrams from existing code with some quality, then I think you will need to look expensive programs such as IBM Rational Software Architect.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I was searching for opensource to prevent paying to IBM :)